# PyMesh Installation on Python 3.6 Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, mesh

I am trying to install Pymesh on Python 3.6.

In my first try, I installed through pip, however it installed a wrong PyMesh than I wanted. 
It installed the following, https://pypi.org/project/pymesh/, while I wanted https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I uninstalled it, and tried installing the later PyMesh, however no luck. There were no instructions for windows. I downloaded the source from github. I extracted and pasted it in C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages

Then I ran `python3 setup.py build` - when an error showed up, I also tried `python3 setup.py install`, which worked. However, I am unable to do a simple basic command mentioned in the web page: https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html

It is saying pymesh does not have module name load_mesh.

Looking for the process or thoughts on how to properly install pyMesh for Windows.

Comment: Did you have any luck with that? I'm facing similar issues and I'm thinking it's just not compatible with windows.

Comment: No luck, feel free to post a solution, if you find one

Answer (score 0):

My go to solution for problems like this on Windows is always to try it in a conda env first.  If that fails, use Docker.